# How to leave margin between elements in the stack panel

Tags: wpf

I use the stack panel. It looks like every elements inside is stacking tightly. How to leave some margin between them.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to give each item it's own Margin

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="35" StrokeThickness="5" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Width="100" Height="35" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="35" Margin="5,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
```